# AJAX async:true breaks site on mobile browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am using this function to return search results via AJAX. However, it kills mobile browsers on search. It works if I set it to 'async:false' but this means that I can't have a loading icon.

I cant find anything online to indicate why this would not be working on mobile, when it works fine on desktop.

Any ideas?

```js
(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#filter").on('keyup input', function() {
      delay(function() {
        var input = $('#filter');
        var query = input.val();
        var content = $('#content')

        $.ajax({
          type: 'post',
          url: myajax.ajaxurl,
          async: true,
          data: {
            action: 'load_search_results',
            query: query
          },
          beforeSend: function() {
            input.prop('disabled', true);
            content.addClass('loading');
          },
          success: function(response) {
            input.prop('disabled', false);
            content.removeClass('loading');
            content.html(response);
            myPluginsInit();
          }
        });

        return false;
      }, 700);
    });
  });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'kills mobile browsers'?

Comment: getting the 'Oh Snap' error on chrome, and the onscreen keyboard is frozen. Sorry, could have phrased it better.

Comment: I have tried changing it to a button, not a keyup event and the same thing happens, so it must be something to do with the AJAX itself?

Comment: remove the event all together, leaving just the ajax. same result? How big of a result are you trying to load?

Comment: That's odd. I can't see why that would happen unless there's some kind of recursion being invoked

Comment: disabling the input on sending and enable on finish.... that seems like a bad idea

Comment: ^^ that's something you do for submit events, not keyup/change events. you'll interrupt the user's typing.

Comment: The AJAX only fires 700ms after they have finished typing, so it shouldnt interrupt their typing. Either way, even if I change this to submit on click it still doesnt work on mobile unless its set to async:false, so im a bit stuck still.

Comment: If you remove the disable, enable does the issue go away?

Comment: nope, still get the 'AW SNAP' page. There is a delay (probably of around 700ms.... just a guess) and then BAM, slapped with the error.

Comment: However, If I remove the content.addClass('loading'); & content.removeClass('loading'); it works again (but obviously that means I still dont have a loading animation). Very confused.

Comment: Sounds like a general race condition that only surfaces on mobile networks with slower connections

Comment: I dont know what the issue was, but I have instead added a div to the page and then added the loading class to that. It seems to work now.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this problem by adding a separate 'loader' div with an ID of loader to my page, and add the loading class to this instead. The code now looks like this:

```
(function($) {

$(document).ready(function() {


$("#filter").on('keyup input', function(){
delay(function(){
var input = $('#filter');
var query = input.val();
var content = $('#content')

$.ajax({
    type : 'post',
    url : myajax.ajaxurl,
    async: true,
    data : {
        action : 'load_search_results',
        query : query
    },
    beforeSend: function() {
        input.prop('disabled', true);
        $('#loader').addClass('loading');
    },
    success : function( response ) {
        input.prop('disabled', false);
        $('#loader').removeClass('loading');
        content.html( response );
        myPluginsInit();
    }
});

return false;
  }, 700 );
 });
});

})( jQuery );
```

Answer (score 0):

You're problem is still in your `keyup input` handler. I'm not sure where the function `delay` is declared (I'm assuming it's some wrapper around `setTimeout`). However it doesn't really matter.

The issue is that the handler fires for every input and keyup event. The "delay" is inside that. All the "delay" is doing is "waiting" before it makes the ajax call but an ajax call is still being created for every keyup and input event.

This means that a lot of ajax calls are being created and on a mobile platform that's a problem. I'm not exactly certain when (or how often) you need to make the call to the server but to see what I'm talking about just add the line I've included below:

```
(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#filter").on('keyup input', function() {
            console.log('handling keyup or input') // add this line and watch them stack up
            delay(function() {
                var input = $('#filter');
                var query = input.val();
                var content = $('#content')

                $.ajax({
                    type: 'post',
                    url: myajax.ajaxurl,
                    async: true,
                    data: {
                       action: 'load_search_results',
                       query: query
                    },
                    beforeSend: function() {
                        input.prop('disabled', true);
                        content.addClass('loading');
                    },
                    success: function(response) {
                        input.prop('disabled', false);
                        content.removeClass('loading');
                        content.html(response);
                        myPluginsInit();
                    }
                });

                return false;
            }, 700);
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Sorry, totally forgot about the delay function, even though I mentioned it above. It looks like this:

var delay = (function(){
  var timer = 0;
  return function(callback, ms){
    clearTimeout (timer);
    timer = setTimeout(callback, ms);
  };
})();